# passing variable from Controller to View

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a problem, Ive been making my own MVC app but there seems to be a problen in passing variables between model and controller. Output from controller is a single variable containing some json format data and it looks simple.

Controller

```
<?php 

class controllerLib 
{
     function __construct() 
     {
            $this->view = new view();
     }

     public function getModel($model) 
     {
            $modelName = $model."Model"; 
            $this->model=new $modelName();
     }
}

 class controller extends controllerLib
 {
     function __construct()
     {
            parent::__construct();
     } 

     public function addresses($arg = false) 
     {
            echo'Addresses '.$arg.'<br />';

            $this->view->render('addressesView');

            $this->view->showAddresses = $this->model->getAddresses(); 
     }
 }

 ?>
```

View

```
 <?php 

 class view
 {
    function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function render($plik)
    {
        $render = new $plik();
    }
 }

 class addressesView extends view
 {
    public $showAddresses;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        require 'view/head.php';

        $result = $this->showAddresses;


        require 'view/foot.php';
    }
 }


 ?>
```

Now problem is that $this->showAddresses does not pass to view and im stuck.

Comment: A lot of basic things go wrong, I recommend you to read about the OOP and MVC model again. I will try to correct this code later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code have various issues:

1. render() save the new View in a local var so that don't exists after the function end
2. You can't expect `$this->showAddresses` to have a value at the constructor time.

You should implement the render() method as a method outside of the View constructor.

```
function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();

    require 'view/head.php';

    $result = $this->showAddresses; // (NULL) The object is not created yet


    require 'view/foot.php';
}
```

View class:

```
public function factory($plik) // Old render($splik) method
{
    return new $plik();
}
```

addressesView class:

```
function __construct() 
{
  parent::__construct();
}

function render()
{
    require 'view/head.php';

    $result = $this->showAddresses; // Object is created and the field has a value


    require 'view/foot.php';
}
```

Controller class:

```
 $view = $this->view->factory('addressesView');
 $view->showAddresses = $this->model->getAddresses(); 
 $view->render();
```

Comment: I recommend you to read about Factory pattern design. The code in the answer aim to reduce the number of changes but your View class should be an independent class and your addressesView should implement, at least, an interface

Comment: Done as well as independent view and interfece :)